# iOS UIImageView scale

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiimageview

I need to make a table of different images which has to fit exactly to a iPad Mini 2.

So I have a picture with height = 60 and width = 621. If I put these sizes into the `UIImageView`, the picture fits nearly the whole screen of my iPad.

Maybe someone can tell me why this happens, as I am very new to programming with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the photo is either not constrained to a scaled size (ex 30x310 to get a 2x downscale) or it is not in a stack, in the table. Try putting the images in a stack and constrain the stack. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: So, I need to set the size of the UIImageView to 30x310, that it has 60x620?

Answer (score 0):

An UIImageView holds an image.

If it stretches to fill the entire screen, it is likely that the size of your UIImageView is quite large. By default, the image will stretch and fill the space of your UIImageView.

If you want the image to stay in ratio, and stretch to the UIImageView:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

If you want the image to stay exactly the way it is:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Comment: Ok I see, thank you.
But as I want to use "absolute position" I need to enter the pixel size of my image, also I want to place it by entering the leading space pixels. But everything is scaled by 2. Is there a way that I can enter 30 pixel leading, and it is 30 pixel leading, and not 60 pixels?

Comment: UIImage has a property "scale". Maybe that has been set? You'll have to show the code you used to create the UIImageView (+ the UIImage assignment)